# How to set a colspan in an android gridview cell

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

How do i have a GridView with some cells that span across columns? I have a several sets of data that need to be dynamically loaded(so grid layout is not what i need) and visually presented in different ways on the GridView. Below is a graphical representation of what i'm able to achieve, the 'x' shows cells that display something while the empty cells don't show anything

[image: Unwanted]

With what i have here, there's an ugly cell at the center when I want to display 4 items in one row.

What i want is to be able to have one row evenly displaying 5 items, while another row can display 4 items and so on.. The graphic below shows what i want to achieve

[image: Wanted]

I want to use the Gridview because the data to populate the grid is provided dynamically. So i'm able to use the gridview's adapter. If there's another approach to this other than the gridview then i'm open for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer.. You can not use a `GridView` component for that because it works in terms of columns. The column count must be defined.

What you can do is to use a custom `LayoutManager` for `RecyclerView`. Here is a good example. [RecyclerView LayoutManager different span counts on different rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112291/recyclerview-layoutmanager-different-span-counts-on-different-rows)

There is a lot of information on this topic nowadays because this kind of customization is the main purpose of `RecyclerView`. Google apps use this to follow material design pattern.