# Spannable RecyclerView like Snapchat-Discover

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, snapchat

Im trying to create a spannable recyclerView like the following image using the TwoWayView library: https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view

But I'm unable to get the desired view and there are empty cells being left out.

```
        final SpannableGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams lp = (SpannableGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) itemView.getLayoutParams();

        //final int span1 = (itemId == 0 || itemId == 3 ? 2 : 1);
        //final int span2 = (itemId == 0 ? 2 : (itemId == 3 ? 3 : 1));

        int span1 = 0; //h
        int span2 = 0; //w

        switch(itemId)
        {
        case 0:
            span1 = 2;
            span2 = 1;
            break;

        case 1:
            span1 = 2;
            span2 = 1;
            break;

        case 2:
            span1 = 2;
            span2 = 1;
            break;

        case 3:
            span1 = 3;
            span2 = 1;
            break;

        case 4:
            span1 = 3;
            span2 = 1;
            break;

        case 5:
            span1 = 4;
            span2 = 3;
            break;

        case 6:
            span1 = 2;
            span2 = 1;
            break;

        case 7:
            span1 = 2;
            span2 = 1;
            break;

        case 8:
            span1 = 2;
            span2 = 1;
            break;

        case 9:
            span1 = 2;
            span2 = 1;
            break;

        case 10:
            span1 = 4;
            span2 = 3;
            break;
        }

        final int colSpan = span2;
        final int rowSpan = span1;

        if (lp.rowSpan != rowSpan || lp.colSpan != colSpan) 
        {
            lp.rowSpan = rowSpan;
            lp.colSpan = colSpan;
            itemView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
```

XML:

```
<org.lucasr.twowayview.widget.TwoWayView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/TwoWayView"
    app:twowayview_layoutManager="ListLayoutManager"/>
```

Ref:
[image]

**Edit 1**
I was able to solve this by changing the rowWidth to 12 in the XML and the following spans:

```
        //PADDING-- left / top / right / bottom
    switch(itemId%11)
    {
    case 0:
        span1 = 4;
        span2 = 7;
        //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1);
        break;

    case 1:
        span1 = 4;
        span2 = 7;
        //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels2, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels2, dpAsPixels1);
        break;

    case 2:
        span1 = 4;
        span2 = 7;
        //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1);
        break;

    case 3:
        span1 = 4;
        span2 = 7;
        //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1);
        break;

    case 4:
        span1 = 8;
        span2 = 14;
        //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels2, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1);
        break;

    case 5:
        span1 = 4;
        span2 = 7;
        //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1);
        break;

    case 6:
        span1 = 6;
        span2 = 10;
        //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels2, dpAsPixels1);
        break;

    case 7:
        span1 = 6;
        span2 = 10;
        //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1);
        break;

    case 8:
        span1 = 8;
        span2 = 14;
        //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels2, dpAsPixels1);
        break;

    case 9:
        span1 = 4;
        span2 = 7;
        ///holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1);
        break;

    case 10:
        span1 = 4;
        span2 = 7;
        //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: So you are trying to create a top list that is scrolling after some time and below a list with different kinds of sizes of cards?

Comment: where do you change the rowWidth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by changing the rowWidth to 12 in the XML and the following spans:

```
        //PADDING-- left / top / right / bottom
switch(itemId%11)
{
case 0:
    span1 = 4;
    span2 = 7;
    //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1);
    break;

case 1:
    span1 = 4;
    span2 = 7;
    //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels2, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels2, dpAsPixels1);
    break;

case 2:
    span1 = 4;
    span2 = 7;
    //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1);
    break;

case 3:
    span1 = 4;
    span2 = 7;
    //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1);
    break;

case 4:
    span1 = 8;
    span2 = 14;
    //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels2, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1);
    break;

case 5:
    span1 = 4;
    span2 = 7;
    //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1);
    break;

case 6:
    span1 = 6;
    span2 = 10;
    //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels2, dpAsPixels1);
    break;

case 7:
    span1 = 6;
    span2 = 10;
    //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1);
    break;

case 8:
    span1 = 8;
    span2 = 14;
    //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels2, dpAsPixels1);
    break;

case 9:
    span1 = 4;
    span2 = 7;
    ///holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1);
    break;

case 10:
    span1 = 4;
    span2 = 7;
    //holder.cont_frienddetail.setPadding(dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1, dpAsPixels0, dpAsPixels1);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Imagine taking your example image and extending the vertical boundary of each cell through the entire screen.  If you did that, you'd see that there are six columns.  And that is the insight that will solve your problem.

Now you can do this with a regular `RecyclerView` and `GridLayoutManager`, and not have to depend on somebody fixing all the bugs in their GitHub library.

Create a `GridLayoutManager` with 6 columns, then specify a custom `SpanSizeLookup` that will make your cells different widths.

In your example image, the three cells in the first row would span 2 columns each.  The two larger cells in the second row span 3 columns each.  The bottom left cell spans 4 columns.

So now all you have to do is create a `SpanSizeLookup` that will set the correct widths.

```
    // Create a grid layout with 6 columns
    // (least common multiple of 2 and 3)
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 6);

    layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {

            int widthClass = determineWidth(position) // TODO here you figure out what the cell width should be

            switch (widthClass) {
            case SMALL:
                return 2;   // fits 3 per row

            case MEDIUM:
                return 3;   // fits 2 per row

            case LARGE:     // fits 2 per row, one LARGE and one SMALL
                return 4;

            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("don\'t know about widthClass " + widthClass);
            }
        }
    });
```

You can view my original answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112291/recyclerview-layoutmanager-different-span-counts-on-different-rows/31113461#31113461).

Comment: How would I change the heights?

Comment: Also, I was able to solve it using the existing library. But would still prefer not using it if possible.

Comment: In my answer span2 refers to the height

Answer (score -1):

See this link [The link you getting help](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/recyclerview-in-android/)

[Full source code](https://github.com/noorintelli/RecyclerViewDemoApp)

[image]

**Code.**

> MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TYPE_VERTICAL_LIST= "Vertical List";
    public static final String TYPE_HORIZONTAL_LIST= "Horizontal List";
    public static final String TYPE_GRID_VIEW = "Grid View";
    public static final String TYPE_HORIZONTAL_GRID_VIEW_STAGGERED = "HorizontalStaggeredGridView";
    public static final String TYPE_VERTICAL_GRID_VIEW_STAGGERED = "VerticalStaggeredGridView";
    public static final String TYPE = "TYPE";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    attachFragment(TYPE_VERTICAL_LIST);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    /** Return false so that we can capture {@link PlaceholderFragment#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)} events in {@link PlaceholderFragment} Fragment*/
    return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_vertical_list:
        attachFragment(TYPE_VERTICAL_LIST);
        break;
        case R.id.action_horizontal_list:
        attachFragment(TYPE_HORIZONTAL_LIST);
        break;
        case R.id.action_grid_view:
        attachFragment(TYPE_GRID_VIEW);
        break;
        case R.id.action_vertical_grid_view_staggered:
        attachFragment(TYPE_VERTICAL_GRID_VIEW_STAGGERED);
        break;
        case R.id.action_horizontal_grid_view_staggered:
        attachFragment(TYPE_HORIZONTAL_GRID_VIEW_STAGGERED);
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /** Attach placeholder fragment here and show different kind of RecyclerView flavours eg List or grid based on user selection in the options menu.*/
    private void attachFragment(String type){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(TYPE, type);
    PlaceholderFragment placeholderFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
    placeholderFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, placeholderFragment).commit();
    }
    }
```

> PlaceholderFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "PlaceholderFragment";
    /*Number of columns in the grid view*/
    private static final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 2;
    /*Total number of items in the RecyclerView*/
    private static final int NUM_OF_ITEMS = 100;
    private ArrayList<DataModel> mDataModels;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    private int addItemCount = 0;


    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Must be set in order to capture menu item click events. If you don't set it, it will not show the menu items set in the Activity holding this fragment.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);


        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = null;
        String type = getArguments().getString(MainActivity.TYPE);
        if( type.equals(MainActivity.TYPE_VERTICAL_LIST)){
            /*LinearLayoutManager to show a vertical list view*/
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        }else if(type.equals(MainActivity.TYPE_HORIZONTAL_LIST)){
            /*LinearLayoutManager to show a horizontal list view*/
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        }else if(type.equals(MainActivity.TYPE_GRID_VIEW)){
             /*LinearLayoutManager to show a grid view. We can specify number of columns in the grid.*/
            layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), NUM_OF_COLUMNS);

        }else if(type.equals(MainActivity.TYPE_HORIZONTAL_GRID_VIEW_STAGGERED)){
             /*LinearLayoutManager to show a staggered grid view. We can specify number of columns in the grid.*/
            //spanCount:   If orientation is vertical, spanCount is number of columns. If orientation is horizontal, spanCount is number of rows.
            //orientation: StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL or StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL
            layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3/*span count*/, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL/* orientation*/);

        }else if(type.equals(MainActivity.TYPE_VERTICAL_GRID_VIEW_STAGGERED)){
             /*LinearLayoutManager to show a staggered grid view. We can specify number of columns in the grid.*/
            //spanCount:   If orientation is vertical, spanCount is number of columns. If orientation is horizontal, spanCount is number of rows.
            //orientation: StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL or StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL
            layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2/*span count*/, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL/* orientation*/);

        }

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mDataModels = getDataModelList();
        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mDataModels, type);

        /*Third party ItemDecoration found from https://gist.github.com/alexfu/0f464fc3742f134ccd1e*/
        RecyclerView.ItemDecoration verticalDivider  = new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST);
        RecyclerView.ItemDecoration horizontalDivider = new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL_LIST);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(horizontalDivider);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(verticalDivider);

        // this is the default;
        // this call is actually only necessary with custom ItemAnimators
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_add_item:
                addItem();
                break;
            case R.id.action_delete_item:
                deleteItem();
                break;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /** Creates and returns the data items to be shown in the Recycler View*/
    private ArrayList<DataModel> getDataModelList(){
        ArrayList<DataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ITEMS; i++) {
            dataModels.add(new DataModel("Title:"+i));
        }

        return dataModels;
    }


    /** Adds a single item in the existing list*/
    private final void addItem(){
        //Adding item at top second position(i.e. at index 1).
        mDataModels.set(1, new DataModel("Added Item "+String.valueOf(++addItemCount)));
        //See for similar methods to know more item insertion options
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemInserted(1);
    }

    /** Deletes a single item from the existing list*/
    private void deleteItem(){
        //Removing top item
        mDataModels.remove(0);
        //See for similar methods to know more item removing options
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(0);
    }

}
```

> ListItemViewHolder.java

```
public class ListItemViewHolder extends ViewHolder {

ImageView imgView;
TextView title;

public ListItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_title);
    imgView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_icon);
 }
 }
```

> DividerItemDecoration.java

```
 import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;


public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[]{
            android.R.attr.listDivider
    };

    public static final int HORIZONTAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL;

    public static final int VERTICAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL;

    private Drawable mDivider;

    private int mOrientation;

    public DividerItemDecoration(Context context, int orientation) {
        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS);
        mDivider = a.getDrawable(0);
        a.recycle();
        setOrientation(orientation);
    }

    public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
        if (orientation != HORIZONTAL_LIST && orientation != VERTICAL_LIST) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid orientation");
        }
        mOrientation = orientation;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
        if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
            drawVertical(c, parent);
        } else {
            drawHorizontal(c, parent);
        }
    }

    public void drawVertical(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
        final int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
        final int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

        final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                    .getLayoutParams();
            final int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
            final int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
            mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            mDivider.draw(c);
        }
    }

    public void drawHorizontal(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
        final int top = parent.getPaddingTop();
        final int bottom = parent.getHeight() - parent.getPaddingBottom();

        final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                    .getLayoutParams();
            final int left = child.getRight() + params.rightMargin;
            final int right = left + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
            mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            mDivider.draw(c);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, int itemPosition, RecyclerView parent) {
        if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
            outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight());
        } else {
            outRect.set(0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

> RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListItemViewHolder> {


    private ArrayList<DataModel> mDataModels;
    private String mType;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> mDataModels, String mType) {
        this.mDataModels = mDataModels;
        this.mType = mType;
    }


    @Override
    public ListItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_view, parent, false);
        return new ListItemViewHolder(itemView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DataModel model = mDataModels.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(model.getTitle());
        if(position % 2 == 0){
            if(mType.equals(MainActivity.TYPE_VERTICAL_GRID_VIEW_STAGGERED)){
                holder.imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lollipop);
            }else{
                holder.imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lollipop_h1);
            }

        }else if(position % 3 == 0){
            if(mType.equals(MainActivity.TYPE_VERTICAL_GRID_VIEW_STAGGERED)){
                holder.imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lollipop1);
            }else{
                holder.imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lollipop_h2);
            }
        }else{
            if(mType.equals(MainActivity.TYPE_VERTICAL_GRID_VIEW_STAGGERED)){
                holder.imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lollipop2);
            }else{

                holder.imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lollipop_h3);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataModels.size();
    }
}
```

> DataModel.java

```
public class DataModel {

    private String title;

    public DataModel(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

> fragment_main.xml

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_recycler_view"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> item_recycler_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageview_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/lollipop"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textview_title"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But this seems to be more like staggeredGridLayout. I'd like the appearance to be like the image attached. I've actually managed it with the library mentioned, but there seems to be some error when I use Glide/Picasso ; any tips on that?

Comment: Why not you can add at adapter with picasso Universal library or gilde with your url picture or destination path...