# multiple RecyclerViews above eachother with content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i want to make a layout with multiple RecyclerViews like this

```
<ScrollView
<LinearLayout << content here
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
<LinearLayout << content here
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
<LinearLayout << content here
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
</ScrollView>
```

but the problem in this layout that the RecyclerView is not recycling item because its inside a scroll view ,,, my question is How do other apps achieve this effect of multiple vertical lists ?
How can i scroll content out ?
what are the options i can do ?

> Note : RecyclerViews will have different LayoutMnager

Answer (score 0):

You can use NestedScrollView. Don't use scrollview.. Give also "recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)". It will solve your issue

Comment: NestedScrollView  same thing views do not get recycle

Answer (score 0):

If all recyclerviews scroll vertically you can just use **GridLayoutManager** with different span counts (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31112291/1512199)) and one recyclerview with different view types (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type))

Comment: this is possible but its very limted when you have a lot of defrrent items ,,, and its very time consuimg

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to create a 'mother' RecyclerView that hosts other recycler views. Make you Items like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/your_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/item_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then make an appropriate ViewHolder  :

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView textView;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.your_content);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_rv);
    }
}
```

Now, setup the RecylerView when Binding :

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.textView.setText("This is content " + i);
    viewHolder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(activity, 2, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    viewHolder.recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
}
```